# Cohomology of degree $d$ line bundles on projective curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $C$ a genus $g$ smooth projective curve over $k$ and $A=Pic^d(C)\subseteq Jac(C)$ the moduli variety of all deg $d$ line bundles. For any degree $d$ line bundle $L$ on $C$ (i.e $L \in A(k)$), we can consider $f_i(L)=\text{dim}_kH^i(C,L)$ for $i=0,1$. By Riemann-Roch theorem, we know $f_0(L)-f_1(L)=d+1-g$. My question is, what do we know about $f_0(L)$ as a function on $A(k)$? For general $L$, what is $f_0(L)$? Is $f_0$ constant on some open subset or upper semi-continuous?

Example: If $g=1$ and $d=0$, then $f_0(L)=0$ for non-trivial $L$. If not, there is a nonzero section on $L$. Note $C$ is a elliptic curve in this case, and multiplication by $[-1]$  gives $[-1]^*L=L^{-1}$ hence both $L$ and $L^{−1}$ have a non-trivial section so $L$ is trivial.

What about the general case?

Edit: Thanks for the answer, could we even compute $f_0(L)$ like the $d=0$ case?

Comment: Consider the universal line bundle $\mathcal{M}$ on $A \times C$ and let $pr_1 : A \times C \rightarrow A$. Then $\mathcal{M}$ is flat over $A$. Now the cohomology of $f_i(\mathcal{M}_p) = H^i(C, \mathcal{M}_p)$, where $p \in A(k)$ is upper semi-continuous. So yeah it seems like $f_i$ is semi-continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $g$ one has 
$$
H^0(C,L) = 
\begin{cases}
k, & \text{if $L \cong \mathcal{O}_C$},\\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
So, $f_0$ for $ = 0$ is zero away from the origin of $Pic^0(C)$.

For arbitrary $d$ the function $f_0$ is upper semi-continuous. The corresponding stratification of $Pic^d(C)$ is not so easy to describe. The subvariety, where $f_0 > 0$ is the image of the natural map 
$$
\gamma \colon S^d(C) \to Pic^d(C). 
$$
The subvariety $f_0 > 1$ is the critical locus for this map, and more generally, the subvariety $f_0 \ge i$ coincides with the locus of points, over which the dimensions of the fibers of $\gamma$ is at least $i$.

Comment: Thank you! I recognize that deg is the sum of order and poles..

Comment: Maybe a more good question is to consider deg $d$ part of Picard variety...

Comment: I edit the question and thank you for the help...! My original motivation is to consider cohomology of line bundle on projective varieties such like curves and abelian varieties...

Comment: @zzy: I expanded the answer.

Comment: Now I figure out that $f_0=0$ on a nonempty open subset of $Pic^d(C)$ if $d<g$, and $f_0>0$ if $d>2g$. Maybe we can say more?

Comment: @zzy: Look into the Arbarello-Cornalba-Griffiths-Harris book.

Comment: thank you for pointing out this book.